# How to transform ListPlot ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am sure that this is a standard question, but I have not been able to find it, either by a google search or by searching here on the Mathematica StackExchange.

If I have a list plot defined by:

```
GraphicsGrid[{{ListPlot[AmplitudeData, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All], 
               ListPlot[RealData, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]}}]
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: List Plots]

And I wish to transform the axes so that the peak is at $0$, i.e. so the axis values are transformed by $-250$. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html):

```
dat = Table[PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, 0.5], k], {k, 0, 50}];

ListPlot[dat]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[dat, DataRange -> {-25, 25}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you - That does exactly what I wanted it to!